# How can two objects be equal, but only one of them be a Key in my association

Tags: associations

What is going on here? There is an element in `Keys[Dat]` which is equal to `{2.1,2.1}`, but `{2.1,2.1}` is not a Key.

Specifically, in the below code, there is a Key `K0` for which `K0 == {2.1,2.1}` yields `True`, and `Dat[K0]` returns the correct associated value. However `Dat[{2.1,2.1}]` returns `Missing[KeyAbsent,{2.1,2.1}]`. Is this correct behaviour? Because I am totally confused.

#### Code

```
Module[{EVals, EMax = 8, dE = 0.1, DKeys, Dat, K0},
 
 (* make a list EVals *)
 
 EVals = Range[Ceiling[-EMax, dE], Floor[EMax, dE], dE];
 
 (* check elements are there *)
 
 Print["2.0 and 2.1 are in the list EVals"];
 Print@Select[EVals, # == 2.1 || # == 2.0 &];
 
 (* make key list *)
 
 Print["the elements of EVals are used to make a list of keys"];
 DKeys = N@Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, EVals}, {y, EVals}], 1];
 
 (* check some keys are in list *)
 
 Print["the elements of EVals are used to make a list of keys, the \
Keys {2.0,2.0} and {2.1,2.1} are in this list"];
 Print@Select[DKeys, # == {2.1, 2.1} &];
 Print@Select[DKeys, # == {2.0, 2.0} &];
 
 (* contruct association *)
 Dat = Association[(# -> {}) & /@ DKeys];
 
 (* one of the keys is missing *)
 
 Print["however the key {2.1,2.1} is missing"];
 Print[Dat[{2.1, 2.1}]];
 Print[Dat[{2.0, 2.0}]];
 
 (* A key equal to {2.1,2.1} is in the key list  *)
 
 Print["Is {2.1,2.1} in the Key List"];
 K0 = First@
   Select[Keys[Dat], 
    Abs[#[[1]] - 2.1] < 0.05 && Abs[#[[2]] - 2.1] < 0.05 &];
 Print[{2.1, 2.1} == K0];
 
 (* but {2.1,2.1} is not a key *)
 
 Print@MemberQ[Keys[Dat], {2.1, 2.1}];
 Print@MemberQ[Keys[Dat], K0];
 
 (* confirmation *)
 Print@Dat[K0];
 Print@Dat[{2.1, 2.1}];
 
 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with how Mathematica treats numbers and numerical equality, which can be somewhat involved. Each number has a certain precision: exact, finite, or machine precision. (Machine precision is whatever your computer's hardware uses to do floating-point arithmetic, whereas arbitrary-precision numbers are kept track of explicitly.)

Mathematica accounts for this in `==`, and two numbers that might be slightly different expressions, but nonetheless numerically equal up to the given precision, will be considered equal. Change the 4th line of your code to `Print@FullForm@Select[EVals, # == 2.1 || # == 2.0 &];`, and you'll see what the problem is: the thing "equal to `2.1`" is actually `` 2.1000000000000014` ``. (By evaluating `` Precision[2.1000000000000014`] ``, you'll see it's `MachinePrecision`, and so subject to these kind of rounding errors; and you can check that `` 2.1` == 2.1000000000000014` ``!)

The problem is that `Association`s match keys by checking if they're the same *expression*, not that they're equal numerically. You can test expression equality yourself by using `===` (`SameQ`) instead of `==` (`Equal`). And indeed, `` 2.1` === 2.1000000000000014` `` gives `False`.

Whenever Mathematica sees a number entered in (unadorned) decimal format, it assumes `$MachinePrecision` unless told otherwise. One way to avoid this is by using exact numbers, such as `1/10` instead of `0.1`. (Integers such as `8` are assumed to be exact.) You can also convert a decimal to a nearby rational through `Rationalize`—e.g., `Rationalize @ {2.1, 2.1}` gets you `{21/10, 21/10}`.

However, I think there might be a more robust structure here than using an `Association` with numeric keys (of any sort)—e.g., constructing a `Piecewise` function that is defined on intervals around your numbers (or even *at* your numbers, since you can test numerical equality in them), or if you need to, having an association "hidden behind" a function definition which "preprocesses" its input into more robust keys (e.g. strings).

---

If you're looking to emulate `GroupBy` but up to numerical equality, here's one way to do that. We'll preface our functions by `g` for "generalized". In the following, `p` is a function of two arguments used to compare keys, like `Equal` or `SameQ`. `m` is the function used for merging the values. We use the mnemonic `p -> m` as reminder that `p` is applied to compare the keys, and `m` is applied to the values.

```
(* Merge a list of lists of rules by first flattening them \
into one, and then use the more elementary definition of Merge: *)

gMerge[list : {{___Rule}...}, p_ -> m_] := gMerge[Flatten[list,1], p -> m]

gMerge[list : {___Rule}, p_ -> m_] :=
  (* Gather by the first element up to p: *)
  Gather[list, p[First[#1], First[#2]] &] //
  (* Change each list of the form {a -> b, c -> d, ...} into the \
form {a,c, ...} -> {b,d, ...}: *)
  Map[Thread[#, Rule] &] //
  (* Then replace each first part of those rules with their first \
element, since they should all be the same (up to p) (but sort \
first, to get consistent results) and apply f (our merge function) \
to the second: *)
  First[Sort[#1]] -> m[#2] & @@@ # &

(* Operator form: *)

gMerge[p_ -> m_][list_] := gMerge[list, p -> m]

(* Our version of GroupBy: *)

gGroupBy[list_, f_, p_] := 
 (* "Tag" each element with its function value: *)
 f[#] -> # & /@ list //
 (* Apply gMerge, "merging" the list of collected elements by leaving it as is: *)
 gMerge[p -> Identity]
```

An example:

```
(* Numerical equality: *)
(* 10 random real numbers: *)

list = RandomReal[5, 15];

(* Randomly choose (when evaluating) to either make the result of \
Round a machine number or keep it exact: *)

f[x_] := RandomChoice[{N, Identity}]@Round[x]

(* All results: *)
BlockRandom[f[#] -> # & /@ list]

(* Grouped results; BlockRandom should mean we start with the same \
seed as before *)
BlockRandom[gGroupBy[list, f, Equal]]

(* Try merging: *)

g1 = gGroupBy[list, f, Equal];
g2 = gGroupBy[5 - list, f, Equal];

gMerge[{g1, g2}, Equal -> Apply[Union]]
```

This amounts to a sort of rudimentary datatype in Mathematica—we could develop it further by giving it a unique symbolic head (instead of `List`), a validation function (to check the form and to check all keys are distinct up to `p`), maybe an inclusion of `p` in the expression itself, and a way to access keys up to `p`. I'm not sure all that is necessary for the application, though. :)

Comment: So Mma allows data types as keys including numeric keys, as long as the user can find a way to match these exactly while retrieving values? Are there any known restrictions on the data type for keys?

Comment: @Syed Right! as far as I know, a key can be *any* (fully evaluated) mathematica expression. I think the typical/intended use for associations is with "exact" expressions; most of the ones i've seen use strings, (definitionless) symbols, integers, or lists of those.

Comment: @Syed I do think the closest thing to what you want is either 1) to construct a `Piecewise` function, `x |-> Piecewise[{{val1, x == key1}, {val2, x == key2}, ...}]` 2) to define values of a function `f[_?(EqualTo[key1])] = val1; f[_?(EqualTo[key2])] = val2; ...` 3) to simply encode your numbers as a list of pairs `{{key1, val1}, {key2, val2}, ...}` and extract them with something like `NPart[data_, key_] := Last@SelectFirst[data, First[#]==key &]`.

Comment: thanks for the `Piecewise` bit. I was trying to clarify this in my head as other programming languages would just restrict this to strings or ints (and for good reason). I have never been to page 275.2483569723 of any dictionary (nor do i want to) to retrieve anything. But for the benefit of other potential users, you can edit in a simple working example illustrating the usage and the pitfalls. At least they will have been forewarned. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @thorimur. The origin of how I came to use associations here is that I wanted to gather a list ```L1 = {x1,x2 ... }``` into sublists whose elements map to the same value under some function ```f```, and be able to subsequently add to these sublists the elements of a second list ```L2```. I used ```Dat=GroupBy[L1,f]```, and ```Dat=Merge[{Dat,GroupBy[L2,f]},Join@Flatten[#,1]&]``` for these purposes. A better method is not immediately obvious to me. In my code it was helpful to initialised ```Dat```, which is the part I shared. Happy to hear if you have a better method for doing this.

Comment: @ComptonScattering ah, i see! hmm. if you're not looking to retrieve the lists of elements through syntax like `output[2.1]`, you might as well stay away from associations, then. (though I *do* think it would be nice if Mathematica had some built-in version of explicit functions of this sort which could use different tests than `SameQ`. I'll add a possible way of doing this with `Equal` to the answer—apologies in advance if it's not that pretty, though. Maybe someone else will have the "right" solution for numerical equality. :)

Comment: @thorimur Thanks for your input! I'll add that using ```Rationalize``` did fix the code I had. So it really is just a question of whether there is a better framework for this type of problem altogether.

Comment: @ComptonScattering I thought it would be interesting to see if I could make a kind of user-defined `GroupBy` where keys are distinguished only "up to a comparison function `p`". Not sure if it's a better framework than the one you've got working, but it is an option. :)